# using egrep & regex

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Suppose I have the following text file called `inputFile`:

```
hello
HELLO
   Hello World
  wOrld
asdgfsafd 
abc 123
1 3 5 a b
```

and I want to print out the lines containing only one word(any sequence with uppercase/lower case letters), regardless if there are spaces before or after the character, using egrep and regex.

so the output should look like this:

```
hello
HELLO
  wOrld
asdgfsafd
```

The best regex I came up was

```
egrep ' *[a-zA-Z] *$' inputFile
```

but it does't seem to work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How does it "not seem to work"? You can [edit] your post with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `+` after the `[A-Za-z]` so that the regex matches 1-or-more, instead of just a single letter.  You also need to anchor the start of the regex with a `^` (which matches the start of the line, opposite to the `$` matching the end of the line)

```
egrep '^ *[a-zA-Z]+ *$' inputFile
```

You might also want to use `[[:space:]]*` rather than just `*`, so that tabs are matched as well as just spaces.  And `[[:alpha:]]` matches all alpha characters from your locale, not just A-Z.

```
egrep '^[[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]]*$' inputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a good start. 
You're looking for a sequence of one or more letters,
with no other non-blank characters on the same line (before or after). 
Using the **`+`** notation, you can represent a string
of one or more letters, as cas says, with `[a-zA-Z]+`.

You get the rest of the requirement —
no other non-blank characters on the same line (before or after) —
by doing an anchored search
(anchored to the beginning and end of the line,
so it examines the entire line)
for a sequence (possibly null) of blanks,
followed by a non-null sequence of letters,
followed by another sequence (possibly null) of blanks:

```
egrep '^ *[a-zA-Z]+ *$'
```

If you want to include letters from outside the standard Latin alphabet
(e.g., `à`, `é`, `ï`,
and `ô`), and allow whitespace characters
other than space (e.g., Tab), use the character class codes:

```
egrep '^[[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]]*$'
```